# is it possible to handle UICollectionViewCell if i click UIButton outside UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, collectionview

First, I'm sorry but i'm not good at English.

Anyway, i want to select all cells in UICollectionViewCell when i click UIButton outside UICollectionView. But i don't how can i do.

I think it will be possible using collections of UIButton like 5 stars. i just try it.

well.. click button below. The cells in blue is false.

[Main view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dxtwu.png)

if you click 'Everyday' Button, All cells will be red. The cells in red means it is chosen.

[Selected Everyday](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqaA0.png)

if you click 'Weekend' Button, the two rightmost cells will be red. now you know this UICollectionView means 'a week'. so, when 'Weekend' is selected, other 5 days will be blue.

[Selected Weekend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LY2fC.png)

i made this with UICollectionView. but i don't know how i control with button outside. if you need more information and code, or you don't understand i'll edit it or leave a comment. please tell me how.

ViewController code about UIButton and UICollectionView is here. and there is a imageview in CollectionViewCell... that's all...

```
import UIKit

class CreateViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var titleTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var MotivTextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var repeatCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    @IBAction func everydayBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        // empty
    }
    @IBAction func weekdayBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        // empty
    }
    @IBAction func weekendBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        // empty
    }

    var selectedDay = [Bool]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        for _ in 0...7 {
            self.selectedDay.append(false)
        }

        repeatCollectionView.delegate = self
        repeatCollectionView.dataSource = self
        repeatCollectionView.isScrollEnabled = false
    }
}

extension CreateViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? RepeatDayCVCell {
            cell.dayBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

        }
    }
}


extension CreateViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 7
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "RepeatDayCVCell", for: indexPath) as! RepeatDayCVCell

        if self.selectedDay[indexPath.row] == true {
            cell.dayBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        }
        else {
            cell.dayBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        }

        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @doori, first you will need to set your cell selected accordingly to what you want. So, you need set cell selected and others not selected. You understand? So, when you click on a button, you need to set your array ( only values you need to be selected ) and reload your tableview and then make a verification if is selected or not and change color or whatever you want. Understand?

Comment: @DanielArantesLoverde thank you! i fully understand it with your detailed explanation.

Comment: Thanks! Glad i can help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to update your data model and reload the collection view on each button action.

```
@IBAction func weekendBtn(_ sender: Any) {
for index in 0..<selectedDay.count {
    if index < 5 {
        selectedDay[index] = false
    } else {
        selectedDay[index] = true
    }
}
repeatCollectionView.reloadData()
}


@IBAction func weekdayBtn(_ sender: Any) {
for index in 0..<selectedDay.count {
    if index < 5 {
        selectedDay[index] = true
    } else {
        selectedDay[index] = false
    }
}
repeatCollectionView.reloadData()
}

@IBAction func everydayBtn(_ sender: Any) {
for index in 0..<selectedDay.count {
    selectedDay[index] = true
}
repeatCollectionView.reloadData()
}
```

If you want to update the collection view when tapping on cell, update the data in `selectedDay` at that index and reload that row.

Pls excuse the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate your model, I mean about array selectedDay. It depends on the case - you can set true/false at specific indexes. After an update the array, you have to reload data using reloadData() method to see the effect at UI layer.

```
    @IBAction func everydayBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        for i in 0...7 {
            self.selectedDay[i] = true
        }
        repeatCollectionView.reloadData()
    }

    @IBAction func weekdayBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        for i in 0...7 {
            self.selectedDay[i] = i < 5 ? true : false
        }
        repeatCollectionView.reloadData()
    }

    @IBAction func weekendBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        for i in 0...7 {
            self.selectedDay[i] = i > 5 ? true : false
        }
        repeatCollectionView.reloadData()
    }
```

Method collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) is unneeded now. If you tap on any cell, it changes the colour to red.